# How to add Content-Disposition response header for AWS CloudFront

Tags: http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I have a [Content Distribution Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) served by [AWS CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).
Some of my clients want to download this file with a specific filename, so I guess that the natural solution will be injecting a [Content-Disposition response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).

For example, I can use a query parameter `filename` for my CloudFront URL so that this file can be downloaded with the name `awesome.png`

```
https://XXX.cloudfront.net/abc.png?filename=awesome.png
```

Then all I have to do is to add the `Content-Disposition` header to its response.

I thought that it can be easily handled by [CloudFront Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-functions.html) or [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/), but I found that they cannot solve my problem. It's because the query string `filename` is in the HTTP request, but the `Content-Disposition` header must be injected in the HTTP header.

Can anyone suggest a working solution?